# What is 'csd-media-keys' and why does it block my sleep mode?

Tags: cinnamon, kubuntu, sleep

After the most recent upgrade, my laptop does not enter suspend mode anymore. With

```
$pm-suspend
```

it seems to start suspending but the power button never turns off.

I have read about inhibitors, and there is one inhibitor for sleep mode (everything else is 'delay').

```
$systemd-inhibit --list 
username     1000 username 1670 csd-media-keys  handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key Cinnamon handling keypresses                              block
```

I am using Kubuntu.

```
 $uname -a
 Linux schleppi 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 $lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
 Release:        22.04
 Codename:       jammy

 $echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
 X-Cinnamon
```

- What is csd-media-keys?
- Why does it block sleep mode in the first place?
- Can I prevent it from doing so or uninstall if necessary?

Answer (score 3):

### What is csd-media-keys?

It is cinnamon-settings-daemon's media-keys D-Bus API for media players and other functionality.

To quote from the [Docs](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/media-keys/README.media-keys-API):

> The cinnamon-settings-daemon will send key press events from multimedia keys to applications that register their interest in those events. This allows the play/pause button to control an audio player that's not focused for example.

### Why does it block sleep mode in the first place?

That is good question.  Without being at the computer and debugging it is hard to answer.  My guess is that you have still something active on D-Bus which is interfering with the sleep mode.  From your log it looks like it is handling the `handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key` buttons.

### Can I prevent it from doing so or uninstall if necessary?

I'm that not familiar with Cinnamon, but since this is a *plugin* called *media-keys* it could perhaps be removed.  You would have to see for yourself, but you will probably lose that button functionality.  I would ask at github, it could be a bug.

The plugin source is [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-settings-daemon/tree/master/plugins/media-keys).